# How to get a custom collection view cell in sizeForItem

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

As you know, we can set UICollectionView cell sizes using sizeForItemAt method in UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.
But could not get a cell with custom class like the following.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
  // This will raise runtime errors.
  let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
  // Also this.
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "default", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

  return cell.dynamicSize
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: you have more than one custom cell and you need to set every cell with a different size ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var size = super.collectionView(collectionView, layout: collectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: indexPath)

if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell {
    size = cell.dynamicSize
}
return size
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with with **UICollectionViewLayout** like :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let customLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    customLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal // .vertical
    customLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 200) // set the item size here .
    customLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    customLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 30
    myCollectoinView.collectionViewLayout = customLayout

    let anotherCustomLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    anotherCustomLayout....
    myAnotherCollectoinView.collectionViewLayout = anotherCustomlayout
}
```

And if you want to use **sizeForItemAt method** :

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
      if collectionView == myCollectionView {
         // myCollectionView cell size
         return CGSize(width :100 , height : 100)
      }else { 
         // myAnotherCollectionView cell size
         return CGSize(width: 50 m height : 50)
      }
    }
```